# Make python logger non-global

Tags: python, logging, dependency-injection, singleton, python-logging

I would like to inject a custom logger instance into a use case function:

```py
def api_func(project_dir: str, case_name: str) -> None:
    """This function will be called from web API by multiple clients."""
    logger = get_logger(project_dir, case_name)
    some_use_case(logger)
```

This is my `get_logger` function:

```py
import logging
import os

def get_logger(project_dir: str, case_name: str) -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(case_name)  # <- singleton...
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    fh = logging.FileHandler(
        os.path.join(project_dir, 'file.log'),
        delay=True,
    )
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    return logger
```

The issue is that multiple clients
call the same function `api_func` with the `case_name`, that can be occasionally the same.
As a result the same logger instance will be picked up by multiple clients,
leading to a shared log data, which is undesirable.

Can I instantiate loggers under the same name, but that can actually be different objects?

The documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects explicitly mentions to never instantiate logger instances directly, and instead suggests the use of `logging.getLogger` function.
But this returns a reference to the very same object, which I would like to avoid.
What I need is to create a brand new logger instance every time I call `get_logger` function.
Is it possible?

Are there any issues associated with instantiating a logger directly with `logging.Logger`?
The documentation does not seem to mention any of them.

Comment: Even putting aside the fact that `logging.Logger` isn't designed to support this or to behave sensibly if you try it anyway... what happens when the *same* client calls `api_func` twice? You're going to make a new logger every single time, even when you shouldn't.

Comment: Why not just make sure different clients use different names? If `case_name` isn't guaranteed to be different for different clients, then `case_name` is a bad choice of logger name.

Comment: ``case_name`` refers to the name of the operation, which is non-unique, but readable. It is possible to make it unique, but it will lead to poor readability (like inject ``project_dir`` there, for example). However, since the log file is supposed to be stored relative to ``project_dir``, then having the same name for the logger will not be the issue, apart from ``logging.getLogger`` returning the very same instance.

Comment: Creating the same logger instance provides low overhead for my application (relatively rare calls to ``api_func``) so I would prefer creating a new instance every time.

Answer (score 0):

Logger names should relate to an area of the application (e.g. a Python module, or part of one) and never related to application *data* such as a case name. You are not using logging the way it is meant to be used, so it's not surprising that you're running into problems. See [this blog post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2009/09/python-logging-101.html) for a high-level view on logging abstractions (too long to reproduce here).